# iOS:Base View Controller not load xib file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xib

I have two view controller. One is base view controller, the other is derived view controller. Both of them have xibs. And I want the derived view controller to load both base xib and derived xib. When app run, only derived view controller's xib is loaded, and base view controller's xib doesn't load. How can I load base view controller's xib?

Comment: set base controller as rootViewController

Comment: @HariBabu I have another controller as window's rootViewController.

Comment: then check the condition for both